# Showing that the limit is $1/\varphi(q)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, arithmetic-functions

Fix $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and define an arithmetic function $f$ as follows: $f(n)= \log n$ if $n$ is prime, $0$ otherwise. Can we show that the following limit $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum _{n \leq N \\ n\equiv a \bmod q}f(n)$ exists and is equal to $1/{\phi(q)}$?

I tried using the [Siegel-Walfisz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem) and obtained $$\frac{1}{N}\sum _{n \leq N \\ n\equiv a \bmod q}f(n)\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum _{n \leq N \\ n\equiv a \bmod q}\Lambda(n)=\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}+O(\exp(-C(\log N)^{\frac{1}{2}}))$$ for $\gcd(a,q)=1$. The problem with writing down this inequality is that it only gives us $\displaystyle \limsup_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum _{n \leq N \\ n\equiv a \bmod q}f(n)\leq 1/\varphi(q)$.

Also, for the case $\gcd(a,q)\not = 1$, the sum $\frac{1}{N}\sum _{n \leq N \\ n\equiv a \bmod q}f(n)$ becomes zero for $\gcd (a,q)$ composite ($n=q+kq$ and if $\gcd(a,q)=d$, then $d$ must divide $n$. In other words, for $d$ composite, each $n$ is composite and hence the sum is 0.) However, I am not able to say much for $\gcd(a,q)=d$ prime. 
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: If $\gcd(a,q) > 1$, then there is at most one prime $\equiv a \pmod{q}$, so the limit is $0$. For $\gcd(a,q) = 1$ the limit is indeed $1/\varphi(q)$, this is the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions (corresponding to the $\vartheta(x) \sim x$ version of the ordinary PNT). You can use that $\psi(x) - \vartheta(x) \in O(\sqrt{x})$ to show that the contribution of prime powers with exponent $\geqslant 2$ is negligible.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks! I tried writing up my answer using your hint. Would you mind taking a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Daniel Fischer's hint, I have the following:

$\displaystyle \theta(x,q,a):=\sum _{p \leq x \\p \equiv a \bmod q} \log p$ and $\displaystyle \psi(x,q,a)=\sum_{n\leq x\\ n \equiv a\bmod q}\Lambda(n)$. We know that $\displaystyle \theta(x,q,a)-\psi(x,q,a)=O(\sqrt{x})$.

The sum in question, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum _{n \leq N \\ n\equiv a \bmod q}f(n)=\frac{1}{N}\theta(N,q,a)=\frac{1}{N}\Big(\theta(N,q,a)-\psi(N,q,a)\Big)+\frac{1}{N}\psi(N,q,a)$ which is $O(\sqrt{N}/N)+\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}+O(\exp(-C(\log N)^{\frac{1}{2}}))$ for $\gcd(a,q)=1$ using Siegel-Walfisz. The desired limit is $\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}$.

Does this look right?

Comment: Yes, that looks basically right. Note, however, that Siegel–Walfisz (by the way, you misspelled Walfisz, here and in the question, there's no 'c' in the name) is a really huge hammer, the PNT for arithmetic progressions is plenty enough. And the $N$ of $C_N$ in the Siegel–Walfisz theorem is not the same $N$ as the upper limit of your sum, you should change one of those.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about this post. I hope things are correct now.

Comment: Except for the appearance of $\log X$. Your upper limit is called $N$, so it should be $O(\exp(-C\sqrt{\log N}))$. Also change $O(\exp(-C_N(\log X)^{\frac{1}{2}})($ to $O(\exp(-C(\log N)^{\frac{1}{2}}))$ in the question, then all is well and you can with good conscience accept your answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Very kind of you! It was embarrassingly sloppy on my part.